# How to efficiently loop through a huge chunk of text and parse several items?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to scan through MANY blocks of text which could be done with a loop, or a single line of find_all, I think.  Here is a small sample of the text that I'm dealing with.

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
<td>

<td style="padding:0px; width:200px; height:10px;"><svg height="37" width="180px" id="task-run" style="display: block;">

</td>
```

The '' represents nothing, as in this case: `y="3"></text>`

I have code to append everything to a large list and then write that to a data frame.

```
masterlist = []
etc.
masterlist.append(cols)
etc.
df = pd.DataFrame(masterlist)
```

I just can't figure out how to do all the parsing.

Comment: You are parsing HTML with embedded SVG. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python parse HTML", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if all info you required is in well formed table inside HTML, I recommend you try DataFrame.read_html. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html

2) second choice is to try Beautiful Soup as @Tom mentioned already.

3) if you are facing challenge of large file, you should try: [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python) and then parse it line by line.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good case for [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is designed to extract text and attributes from HTML documents that may or may not be well-formed.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this:
foundhref = soup.find('td',{'href':'a'}).get_text()
I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
Also, I tried this:
foundtext = soup.find('td',{'transform':'text'}).get_text()
I get the same exact error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just tried this:
results = pd.read_html(html_page)
That actually does a really nice job, for the most part, but it joins all the numbers together if they are in the same column.  So, in my example above, I'm seeing this: 12141620 ...and... 39
It should be like this: 
12 14 16 '' 20 '' 3 '' 9
Those represent distinct counts of tasks.